# BASH script: How to repalce a string in a file path string?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a bash script to convert my `.docx` files to `.md`:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_path=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")";pwd)
current_dir="${current_path##*/}"
parent_path=$(dirname "$current_path")
dest_path=$parent_path"/"$current_dir"_DEST"

function list_all(){
  for element in $(ls $1)
  do
    path=$1"/"$element
    if [ -d "$path" ]
    then
      # some other operations
      list_all $path
    else
      output=$("$path" | sed "s:$current_path:$dest_path:g")
      echo output
      # some other operations
    fi
  done
}

listall "$current_path"
```

so, if I have a structure like this:

```
- Desktop
  - test
    - this_script.sh
    - subdir1
      - abc.docx
    - subdir2
      - def.docx
```

after running this script, I will get:

```
- Desktop
  - test
    - this_script.sh
    - subdir1
      - abc.docx
    - subdir2
      - def.docx
  - test_DEST
    - subdir1
      - abc.md
    - subdir2
      - def.md
```

That means, the `sed` part should:

replace `/Users/someone/Desktop/test`

with `/Users/someone/Desktop/test_DEST`

in `/Users/someone/Desktop/test/subdir1/abc.docx`.

but it doesn't work:

```
line xx: /Users/someone/Desktop/test/subdir1/abc.docx: cannot execute binary file
```

What should I do now?

I'm doing this in macOS 10.15.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```sh
output=$("$path" | sed "s:$current_path:$dest_path:g")
```

This line tells BASH it should run an executable file whose path is in `$path` and then process its output with `sed`, whereas you want `$path` itself to be passed to `sed` as an input string.

This is how it needs to be:

[option 1; the trivial one]

```sh
output=$(echo "$path" | sed "s:$current_path:$dest_path:g")
```

[option 2; a rather advanced technique called [here-string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)]

```sh
output=$(sed "s:$current_path:$dest_path:g" <<<"$path")
```

[P.S.:] Bear in mind that unquoted path variables tend to misbehave when paths they contain have space characters in them. Always double quote path vars.

[P.S.#2:] Here, I fixed the script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

current_path="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)"
current_dir="${current_path##*/}"
parent_path="$(dirname "$current_path")"
dest_path="$parent_path/${current_dir}_DEST"

list_all() {
  IFS=$'\n'
  for element in $(ls "$1")
  do
    path="$1/$element"
    if [ -d "$path" ]
    then
      # some other operations
      list_all "$path"
    else
      output="$(echo "$path" | sed "s:$current_path:$dest_path:g")"
      echo "$output"
      # some other operations
    fi
  done
}

list_all "$current_path"
```

Output:

```
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/10.6.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/10.6.app/Contents/MacOS/DPE
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/10.6.app/Contents/Resources/main.icns
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/MacOS/Controllers Lite
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/PkgInfo
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/Resources/archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Main.nib
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/Resources/lite-icon.icns
/Users/u1/Desktop_DEST/Controllers Lite.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
```

Comment: thx, but it seems not working on my Macbook. now `output` and `path` are exactly the same. Does `sed` works differently on macOS?

Comment: @EliasAbel Wait a sec, I\`ll check it on my 10.11 machine.